# NSManagedObjectContext.performAndWait{} cause a crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift5, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Im not sure what am I doing wrong here, but due to this my app crashes. This is my coredata stack in the AppDelegate looks like follow.

```
lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()

lazy var cacheContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
return self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
}()

lazy var updateContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
let _updateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
_updateContext.parent = self.viewContext
return _updateContext
}()
```

Then I created a Singleton class to manage my CoreData operations as bellow.

```
class StorageManager:NSObject {

  private override init() {}

  private static var SMInstance: StorageManager?

  public static var shared : StorageManager {
    if SMInstance == nil {
      SMInstance = StorageManager()
    }

    return SMInstance!
  }



//Represent a single context for all the operations with lazy loading
lazy var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      appDelegate.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
      return appDelegate.viewContext
}()


lazy var privateMOC : NSManagedObjectContext = {
         let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
         return appDelegate.updateContext
}()


 private func synchronize() {
  do {

    try self.privateMOC.save() 

      self.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
          do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()

            print("Saved to main context")
          } catch {
            print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
          }

      }
  } catch {
    print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

 }

}
```

Sample Save Method to save data in the same class was written as follow. but this at times this gives me this error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x1f0ec200> was mutated while
being enumerated...

```
func savedata() {     

  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

   let entity = User(context: self.privateMOC)
       
     entity.name = "JOHN PAUL"
        
    //IT crash here
     self.privateMOC.performAndWait {
          self.synchronize()
      }

  })

}
```

Comment: You asked this question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63369380/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-core-data-multiple-thread-execution-in-a-private). Please don't post the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably because you are creating `User` entity in background context, but performing the operation on main thread.

Remove `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

For more information about Core Data and threads read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background).

Edit: The creation of objects/entities in private/background context should be like this:

```
let privateMOC = self.privateMOC
privateMOC.performAndWait {
     let entity = User(context: privateMOC)
     entity.name = "JOHN PAUL"
     self.synchronize(privateMOC: privateMOC)
}
```

Also the synchronize function should be like this:

```
private func synchronize(privateMOC: NSManagedObjectContext) {
  do {

    try privateMOC.save() 

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.managedObjectContext.performAndWait {
          do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()

            print("Saved to main context")
          } catch {
            print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \ (error.localizedDescription)")
          }

      }
    }
  } catch {
    print("Could not synchonize data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }

 }
```

Comment: i cannot remove the  DispatchQueue.main.async, if i do so it'll give me errors in the lazy var viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()

Comment: if u do this it'll give u an obvious error "UIApplication.delegate must be used from main thread only"

Comment: I editied my answer, if you took time to think about it why this happens instead of down vote you would have figured it out. :)

Comment: still this causing intermittent crashes and i just wonder could it be cuz of the synchoronise method

Comment: Sure it can, it's the multithread environment that causes crashes like this.

Comment: Any tips to get me off this frustrated issue of intermittent crashes :D